# Convert Java to XML to HTML

Tags: java, xml, project, type-conversion

I have decided on learning XML for my final year project. What I want to do is take some Java source code, convert that Java source code to XML and then use XML to convert to another language. I Have read a lot about XML,ebnf and bnf and various other technologies but i'm struggling to get my head around it. I was wondering if someone who's knowledgeable about this area could give me some tips to get started, for instance which software's I should be using to complete this project, what I should be looking at to begin convert Java to XML etc. Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing my plan at the moment but have become stuck as I have struggled to find out actually what I need to do to do these conversions even though I have done a lot of reading into XML etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your project really has very little to do with XML and more to do with writing a Java compiler since the major task for you will be to translate Java code to an intermediary, neutral format and then converting from that format to "another language". That your intermediary format should happen to be represented in an XML structure is fairly inconsequential in this.

Just as a thought-experiment, remove the intermediary format from your project and consider it again:

*Convert Java source code to another language*

Not trivial at all. Even if we disregard issues like memory models, type conversion/coercion - even converting a basic "hello world" Java class to a syntactically similar language (say C++), using only primitive types, is still very complex.

If your only goal is to learn XML, then I think your project is way, way, way, way too much water over your head.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, my only goal isn't to learn XML but I did want to incorporate XML into it, could you give me some advice on how to start this project please? I have found lot's of information about XML conversion and such but it doesn't really give a clear guideline of how to begin creating the software that will convert from one language to another.

Comment: Not my field at all, I'm afraid. But you want to look at tools for language recognition, lexer and parser tools. I guess antlr could be a way forward (http://antlr.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As pap already mentioned... this is quite a complex thing to do, when it's just to learn XML, still if you'd want to continue, there are a few things you should get / create in order to get the thing done...

- the first thing you should get / create is a java parser, which can "break-up" java code into operators, parameters and such which you can use to build your xml representation
- The second thing to achieve is to create a schema ( xsd ) which fully describes your xml based language ( more or less like BNF, but then in XML )

a piece of transformed "Hello World" code could for instance look like this (although I'm more of a c# guy)

```
<invokeMethod fullname="Console.WriteLine, mscorlib">
  <param type="System.String">Hello World!</param>
</invokeMethod>
```

So there needs to be a schema definition for "invokeMember" which requires a fullname attribute and 0 or more param elements... and so on.

If you got that covered, you'll need to create a sort of "code-generator" ( known as a lexer if I'm not mistaken ) which will convert the parsed java code to XML conforming the schema.

And then you're only halfway...

You could use a xml stylesheet to ultimately transform the XML to another language-type ( which also is quite a difficult task to achieve )

Still... these are just pointers to get you started... and if you do choose to undertake this project... I wish you good luck :-)

Comment: You're right, its not nice. But it seems more and more neccessary on this site. Especially with new users. Nothing against new users, welcome to the SO universe! :) Good answer btw, +1

Comment: thanks :) ( At the same moment you commented I removed my "begging" for an upvote ;) )

Comment: Thanks Chris this is great, do you know what type of programming model I would use to create such a project? For instance would Agile modeling be a good idea? Also do you know what software's I'd need for this would it be just Netbeans/Eclipse?

Comment: I'm convinced you can create all necessary components in Netbeans / Eclipse. I'd try to find a java parser library from communities like google code, and from there on create the converter myself. Especially because you'd like to learn XML

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by parsing java code and start to detect structures in it (like code blocks, control statements, etc). What language you use for that is pretty free, I would choose something that supports XML in a good way and is good at string handling. (I suggest Java, of course :D)

Before you haven't done that, I wouldn't even start thinking about XML itself.

And btw: If you are doing this as a fun project, then it's okay. Otherwise: Why the piping spacenoodle do you need such a converter? ;)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help:) its a contribution to someone else's bigger project :)

Comment: You make a Java-to-someOtherLanguage converter as a contribution to a **bigger** project? You are going to be good buddies after that one... :P

Comment: Haha yeah :) do you know the methodology/modeling I should use for creating this project? I can't really figure out why one would be more beneficial than another for this project. For example waterfall, agile etc.

Comment: Btw, you can upvote answers (like Chris' answer which you stated is very helpful for you). You are awarding the poster of the answer for spending his time to help you. Also at the end, you can choose the answer that was most helpful to you and accept it (by pressing the checkmark under the voter). I would wait a little bit (a day or so) with accepting though as there might be other answers.

Comment: @user123 Unfortunately I don't have any experience in that kind of project (and I doubt there are many that have)...

Comment: Yeah I will do that thanks for the advice, btw did you see my above question? :)